# Chrome won't react to image resize

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a little problem. I created one simple web page and tested with Firefox - everything was fine. Then I realised I should test it with other browsers too and when I opened it in Chrome, every picture was in original size. When I try to modify with CSS ( height, width ) it won't react.

HTML:

```
 <div class="picture">
   <div id="first">
    <ul class="gallery">
      <li>
        <a href="images/morning.png">
          <img src="images/morning.png" alt="">
          <p>Early morning in China</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/night.png">
          <img src="images/night.png" alt="">
          <p>Night sky in Singapore</p>
        </a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/nature.png">
          <img src="images/nature.png" alt="">
          <p>Nature road</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="second">
        <ul class="gallery">
         <li>
           <a href="images/app.png">
           <img src="images/app.png" alt="">
           <p>Weather app for iOS</p>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="images/cold.png">
              <img src="images/cold.png" alt="">
                <p>Cold winter evening</p>
            </a>
         </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/bugs.png">
            <img src="images/bugs.png" alt="">
              <p>Little bugs on the field</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/********* WORKS **********/

.gallery {
   list-style: none;
   margin-right: 35;
   margin-top: 30;
 }

.gallery img {
   width: 250;
   height: 250;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    .flex {
       display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
       display: flex; 
       max-width: 1200px;
       -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
       justify-content: space-around;
        margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .gallery {
    margin-top: 40;
    margin-bottom: 50;
 }

 #first {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
 }

 #second {
   width: 50%;
   float: right;
 } 

.gallery img {
  width: 320;
  height: 320;

 }
}
```

I know my indentation is shit at the moment, so, sorry.

Comment: You should add `unit` like `px` or `%`

Comment: That was the problem, stupid me. Thank you very much, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

chrome will work with unit like `px` or `%` try with px.